# Mapping data in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a basic ember-data model object:

```
App.Group =  DS.Model.extend({
//attributes
});
```

I have json which is structured like this:

```
root.levelone.leveltwo.property
```

I don't want to map this project as is but would like to map property in the json to property in the model like this:

```
App.Group =  DS.Model.extend({
  property: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Is it possible to define a mapping that is different from the incoming json?  I don't have much control on what is coming from the server.

If this is not possible with ember-data, what is the best way to model this deep nesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure quite what you're asking but you can define custom DS.attr transforms.

Something like this maybe? Haven't tested it.

```
DS.attr.transforms.deepNest = {
  from: function(serialized) {
    return this.root2.property
  },
  to: function(deserialized) {
    return { root2: property }
  }
}

property: DS.attr('deepNest', {key: 'root1'})
```

Comment: custom transform is just what I was looking for.

Comment: In current versions of ember-data, this requires DS.Transforms.reopen({ ... })

Comment: can the {key: 'root1'} be received by transforms function if yes how in revision 11

Answer (score 4):

FYI, the latest version of Ember (v.10) requires custom transforms to be defined on the DS.JSONTransforms object.  And the 'to' and 'from' properties have been renamed to 'serialize' and 'deserialize'.

Answer (score 3):

IT changed FROM THIS:

```
DS.attr.transforms.object = {
  from: function(serialized) {
    return Em.none(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
  },
  to: function(deserialized) {
    return Em.none(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
  }
}
```

TO THIS:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('object', {
  fromJSON: function(serialized) {
    return Em.none(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
  },
  toJSON: function(deserialized) {
    return Em.none(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Ember data v 1.0 beta 2 requires this approach:

```
CustomTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    ...
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    ...
  }
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: "customTransforms",

    initialize: function(container, application) {
      application.register('transform:custom', CustomTransform);
    }
});
```